# Entity Framework Exception

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Hi all I have a code like this inside entityframework (I want to change many items at the same time I dont know whether we can use a loop like this but it throws an exception like this:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 get_Item(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Code:

```
        try
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < ids.Count; j++)
            {
                using (OzgorenEntities2 context = new OzgorenEntities2())
                {
                        Stock st = context.Stocks.First(i => i.id == ids[j]);
                        st.stockAmount =  amounts[j];
                        context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
```

to be honest I searched and only find that converting is not working in server side but I dont convert it there what might be solution for me ?

Thanks

Comment: LINQ to Entities is getting tripped up by your using `ids[j]` as a value in your query.  It's totally obvious to you and me that you just want to use a value within the array, but as far as the query provider is concerned, you're trying to access the indexer property called `get_Item` on the array, and it doesn't know how to generate SQL code for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to introduce a variable for the ids value at the given index

```
            using (OzgorenEntities2 context = new OzgorenEntities2())
            {
                    var id = ids[j];
                    Stock st = context.Stocks.First(i => i.id == id);
                    st.stockAmount =  amounts[j];
                    context.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add intermediate variable to storage value `ids[j]`:

```
    try
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ids.Count; j++)
        {
            var tempId = ids[j];
            using (OzgorenEntities2 context = new OzgorenEntities2())
            {
                    Stock st = context.Stocks.First(i => i.id == tempId);
                    st.stockAmount =  amounts[j];
                    context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
```

It is due to nature of IQueriable expressions. LINQ to Entities don't know how to transfer expression `i => i.id == ids[j]` to SQL statement.